# Accessing class member

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How to access non-static class member?

```
class A
{
    int value_ = 0;//I want to access this member in class inheriting from A
};
template<class X = A>
class Y :X
{
static_assert(value_ == 0,"Non-zero not allowed");//here I want to access value_ from X which is A by default. Is this possible?
};
```

Comment: If `value_` is made `public` or `protected` then you can access it from derived classes, but, just like ordinary class members, you can only really use it inside function bodies. I wonder how the construct above would even be useful (if it was legal): You seem to assume that `value_` has a value even before an instance of `Y` (or `A`) has been created. In other words, you assume that `value_` exists at the class level (not the object level). But if so, why don't you just use a static member?

Comment: #jogojapan it cannot be static in my case

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: What sense does a static test (`static_assert`) make for a non-static member? A static test is applied to the class (i.e. the data type itself), not the individual instances. But non-static members generally have a different value in every instance.

Comment: #jogojapan "But non-static members generally have a different value in every instance", yes, and every time I want to test them. static_assert doesn't have to be applied to static members you know.

Comment: `static_assert` can only be applied to constant expressions. A  non-static member can never be a constant expression. And what do you mean you _want to test them every time_? The class definition is not evaluated for every instance. If you want to do something once for every instance, do it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are specifically doing is not possible, for several reasons.

First, `static_assert` requires it's argument to be a compile-time constant expression. `value_` is most assuredly not.

You could try to make it a constant expression by labeling it `constexpr`. But C++11 doesn't allow `constexpr` for non-static data members. And even if it did, that's not going to help because `value_` is a non-static member. As such, *it doesn't exist yet*. It only exists when there is an actual class instance, something that has a `this` pointer. Your `static_assert` expression doesn't create one of those objects, so there's no way to access it.

Therefore, in order to make this "work" (to the extent that "working" does something meaningful), you must:

1. Give `A` a `constexpr` constructor, so that you can create a `constexpr` instantiation of it.
2. Your `static_assert` must actually *create* a type using the `constexpr` constructor and access the data member in question.

Now, if you do this, you're going to find that it doesn't give you what you *want* (based on this statement, since your question didn't explain what exactly it is you're trying to accomplish):

> Secondly, by every time I meant every time object of this class is created, and as a X is a template param it is a constant expression.

Note that `static_assert` is *static*. Whereas "every time object of this class is created" is a *runtime* event. You cannot perform a *static test* on something that happens at runtime.

What you want is *regular* `assert`, not `static_assert`.

Comment: #Nicol Bolas, hey, thanks, will try to follow your instructions and see what'll happen.